# Go invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: golang, указатели

Не понимаю почему не хочет брать с базы даные.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

const db_name = "database"
const db_table = "table"
const db_login = "login"
const db_password= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
const db_host = "localhost"
const db_port = "3306"

type Client struct {
    ID          sql.NullInt64   `json:"id"`
    Name        sql.NullString  `json:"name"`
    Address     sql.NullString  `json:"address"`
    Contacts    sql.NullString  `json:"contacts"`
    Info        sql.NullString  `json:"info"`
}

type PageData struct {
    PageTitle   string
    Year        int
    Clients     []*Client
}

func main() {
    conn, err := sql.Open("mysql", db_login + ":" + db_password + "@tcp(" + db_host + ":" + db_port + ")/" + db_name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rows, err := conn.Query("SELECT id, name, address, contacts, info FROM " + db_table)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    clients := []*Client{}

    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        client := new(Client)

        if err := rows.Scan(&client.ID, &client.Name, &client.Address, &client.Contacts, &client.Info); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        clients = append(clients, client)
    }

    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        data := PageData {
            PageTitle: "TITLE",
            Year: time.Now().Year(),
            Clients: clients,
        }
        tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
        tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    })
    fmt.Println("[@] Server started.")
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    defer conn.Close()
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{.PageTitle}}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style>
            body {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            .table_head {
                background: #5555FF;
            }

            .table_head_element {
                color: white;
            }

            .row:hover {
                background: lightgrey;
            }

            footer {
                position:absolute; 
                bottom:0; 
                width:100%; 
                height:100px; 
            }

            #info {
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <main>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <input type="text" id="search" size="50" placeholder=" SEARCH"/>
                <select>
                    <option disabled selected>FILTER</option>
                    <option value="city">CITY</option>
                    <option value="person">NAME</option>
                    <option value="address">ADDRESS</option>
                    <option value="contacts">CONTACTS</option>
                </select>
                <input type="button" value="<<"/>
                <input type="button" value="<"/>
                1 / 15
                <input type="button" value=">"/>
                <input type="button" value=">>"/>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="table_head">
                        <th class="table_head_element">ID</th>
                        <th class="table_head_element">NAME</th>
                        <th class="table_head_element">ADDRESS</th>
                        <th class="table_head_element">CONTACTS</th>
                        <th class="table_head_element">INFO</th>
                    </tr>
                    {{range Clients}}
                    <tr class="row">
                        <td>{{.ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{.Address}}</td>
                        <td>{{.Contacts}}</td>
                        <td>{{.Info}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {{end}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="info">
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <center>
                <p>
                    &copy; NAME - <span id="year">{{.Year}}</span>
                </p>
            </center></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ошибка:

```
[@] Server started.
2019/12/11 17:16:09 http: panic serving xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:54148: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 10 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0x1a18a7e0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0x9f
panic(0x83231e0, 0x851d4e8)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/panic.go:502 +0x1dc
html/template.(*Template).escape(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/html/template/template.go:95 +0x2d
html/template.(*Template).Execute(0x0, 0x83aec90, 0x1a160bd0, 0x83337a0, 0x1a14b6c0, 0x1a10e830, 0x1)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/html/template/template.go:119 +0x21
main.main.func1(0x83b0b60, 0x1a160bd0, 0x1a198500)
        /home/oyaro/beward/admin/server.go:77 +0x13b
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x1a1bd2d0, 0x83b0b60, 0x1a160bd0, 0x1a198500)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:1947 +0x34
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x8525480, 0x83b0b60, 0x1a160bd0, 0x1a198500)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:2340 +0xf0
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0x1a198300, 0x83b0b60, 0x1a160bd0, 0x1a198500)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:2697 +0x98
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x1a18a7e0, 0x83b0ce0, 0x1a14b2a0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:1830 +0x5dd
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:2798 +0x1f6
2019/12/11 17:17:10 http: panic serving xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:54237: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 13 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0x1a18a8a0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0x9f
panic(0x83231e0, 0x851d4e8)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/panic.go:502 +0x1dc
html/template.(*Template).escape(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/html/template/template.go:95 +0x2d
html/template.(*Template).Execute(0x0, 0x83aec90, 0x1a160cf0, 0x83337a0, 0x1a14bae0, 0x1a10e8a8, 0x1)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/html/template/template.go:119 +0x21
main.main.func1(0x83b0b60, 0x1a160cf0, 0x1a198680)
        /home/oyaro/beward/admin/server.go:77 +0x13b
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x1a1bd2d0, 0x83b0b60, 0x1a160cf0, 0x1a198680)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:1947 +0x34
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x8525480, 0x83b0b60, 0x1a160cf0, 0x1a198680)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:2340 +0xf0
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0x1a198300, 0x83b0b60, 0x1a160cf0, 0x1a198680)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:2697 +0x98
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x1a18a8a0, 0x83b0ce0, 0x1a14b740)
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:1830 +0x5dd
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/net/http/server.go:2798 +0x1f6
```

2 строчка в базе с пустой переменной info

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `address` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `contacts` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `info` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO clients (name, address, info, contacts) VALUE('NAME', 'ADDRESS', 'INFO', 'CONTACTS');
INSERT INTO clients (name, address, contacts) VALUE('NAME2', 'ADDRESS2', 'CONTACTS2');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменять:

```
{{range Clients}}
    <tr class="row">
        <td>{{.ID}}</td>
        <td>{{.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{.Address}}</td>
        <td>{{.Contacts}}</td>
        <td>{{.Info}}</td>
    </tr>
{{end}}
```

На:

```
   {{range .Clients}}
        <tr class="row">
            <td>{{.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{.Address}}</td>
            <td>{{.Contacts}}</td>
            <td>{{.Info}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{end}}
```